# adding line inside textfield in blackberry java

Tags: java, blackberry

i am designing an app in which i need a box as shown below in which inside that i need a bottom line this is used mainly for signing.plz anybody help me i am not able to understand whether should i use textfield or is there any functionality so that user can make his signature with touchpad and without.
my code is 
       BasicEditField enterName = new BasicEditField(" ", "");

now i am currnetly using textfield code as shown below[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure no user would ever want to use a blackberry trackball to sign their signature. Is this application limited to touchscreen? If not, you might need to re-evaluate the design.

Comment: yes,for touchscreen we use this design but for bb trackball i have thought of uploading user signature when user focus on this field. other than these is there other way i can do it.please let me know.

Comment: I dont get it What is signing.plz?what is  purpose of using editField

Comment: @Rakesh sir it is where user do his signature i really do not know whether i should use edit field or not.please let me know what i should use?

Comment: Is there any way of signing in editField,I just know only typing can me done,I am not sure what sort of typing can be done in editField.

Comment: @Rakesh otherthan editfield what else can be used to in touchscreen to do signature

Comment: How Do you validate it,How do you send it,No point in having signature,What purpose do you require Signature,Do any confidential application support signature,Signature is not required unless it is used for very specific purpose